# rewrite htaccess to include www and include rest of url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The following code reditrects the user to www, if the www is missing in the url, however how do you redrirect to the same url just including www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Eg the above redirects:

mydomain.com/goHere/

to

www.mydomain.com

but I would like it to redirect to

www.mydomain.com/goHere/

Thanks in advance to any responders.
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test this in a different browser or clear your browser cache.