# Rewrite url to same url but with www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is similair to this problem. [rewrite htaccess to include www and include rest of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617985/rewrite-htaccess-to-include-www-and-include-rest-of-url)

But i want to have a specific URL to be redirected to a url WITH www.

Example:

http://domain.com/admin > http://www.domain.com/admin

This is what i want to achieve. Other urls must be ignored unless i place the bottom code in the .htaccess file. I don't want that other urls like http://domain.com/work are redirected.

So far i have this.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i want to have a specific URL to be redirected to a url WITH www.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Great! Its works perfect. Now a little addon. What if i want to ignore this rule for subdomains?

Comment: They key being in the `^admin` bit, might not be entirely obvious at first glance.

Comment: To run this rule only for main domain change `RewriteCond` to this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]` and change the domain name to your actual domain.

Comment: Is it possible to get the domain-name dynamically? Because i can never know the domain. I host many websites.

Comment: That is tricky, you can try: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [NC]`

Comment: I think its working, if not.. haha ill come back for more help :$ thanks thusfar